# Check IFRAME URL and reload if found - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the page name of the iframe page (that is on the same server) and if it's not the following name(s): `'index1.php'` or `'indexTOM.php'` then don't do anything if it is that page name then reload the iframe. Here is now I have it set but it doesn't work for some reason the resultNfo is always true and the iframe never reloads?

```
//Check URL of IFRAME
var currentUrl = document.getElementById("frmcontent").contentWindow.location.href;

var word = 'index1.php';
var regex = new RegExp( '\\b' + word + '\\b' );
var resultNfo = regex.test( currentUrl );
if (resultNfo = true){ document.getElementById("frmcontent").contentDocument.location.reload(true); }

var word = 'indexTOM.php';
var regex = new RegExp( '\\b' + word + '\\b' );
var resultNfo = regex.test( currentUrl );
if (resultNfo = true){ document.getElementById("frmcontent").contentDocument.location.reload(true); }
alert('URL is: '+currentUrl+'\n'+resultNfo);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just do `resultNfo = currentUrl.indexOf('indexTOM.php') !== -1` ?

You also have a lot of problems here, you should use a `for` loop really

**Not tested demo**

```
var urls = ['indexTOM.php', 'index1.php'],
    frame = document.getElementById('frmcontent').contentDocument;

for( var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++ ) {
   var url = urls[i];
   if( frame.location.href.indexOf(url) !== -1 ) {
      frame.location.reload()
   }
}
```

Try something along the lines of the above code, it's a lot cleaner.